# Setting an arrayList as a property for a jcr node?

Tags: java, properties, nodes, jcr

Is there any way I can set an arraylist to a property of a jcr node? Anyone figured out a workaround for a better alternative? Ideally it would look like `node.setProperty("name", arrayList<someClass>)`, however eclipse doesn't like converting the array to a value (makes sense). Any thoughts? Anyone had to figure this out before?

Answer (score 0):

You convert/serialise your list to a `String[]` and use

```
setProperty(String name, String[] values)
```

You can create a util class for reading/writing your various collections to a node eg.

```
public <T> void setProperty(Node node, String property, Collection<T> things) 
    throws RepositoryException {

    String[] strings = new String[things.size()];
    int idx = 0;
    for (T thing : things) {
        strings[idx++] = thing.toString();
    }

    node.setProperty(property, strings);
}
```